# Importing a webpage to an Excel spreadsheet using VBA

Tags: forms, vba, excel

I wish to be able to download information from a website to an Excel spreadsheet, which is in [this format – not the actual website](http://share.com/data.aspx?year=2011&month=5&day=18&table=Ford).

I can do a web query with a macro, which works for a particular date and company as above. However, I want to be able - via an input statement - download any date in the web address. I would like the macro to prompt the user to enter the Year, Month and Day and particular Company, in order to download the relevant data.

I do not know how to write code for ANY date & company into the website address above as my attempts do not work!

---

Hopefully this will help. It was taken from a horse racing form website which requires a date!

This was my attempt at code to put a date, but it has bugs!

```
RaceDate = InputBox("Please enter today's date (YYYY/MM/DD)", "Enter Date")
Meeting = InputBox("Enter Location of Race", "Enter Meeting")
Race = InputBox("Enter Race  Number", "Enter Race")
Range("A13").Select
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= "URL;http://tatts.com/racing/formguide.aspx? RaceDate & Meeting & Race"
  , Destination:=Range("$A$13"))
  .Name = "formguide.aspx? RaceDate & Meeting & Race"
  .FieldNames = True
  .RowNumbers = False
  .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
  .PreserveFormatting = True
  .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
  .BackgroundQuery = True
  .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
  .SavePassword = False
  .SaveData = True
  .AdjustColumnWidth = True
  .RefreshPeriod = 0
  .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
  .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
  .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
  .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
  .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
  .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
  .WebDisableRedirections = False
  .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

I know that these two lines will work for a specific date, but I need to adjust for a user inputted date!

```
"URL;http://tatts.com/racing/formguide.aspx?year=2012&month=1&day=20&meeting=QR&race=5" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$13"))
        .Name = "formguide.aspx?year=2012&month=1&day=20&meeting=QR&race=5"
```

Comment: I find your post very hard to understand. Can you show us some code attempts and possibly a working link?

Comment: It is very doable but it would be much easier if you gave us the actual site

Answer (score 0):

Create the web query manually, then change the Connection property based on the user input.  I created a web query from http://tatts.com/racing/2012/7/31/QR and put it in A10.  Then I put the year, month, and day in B1:B3.  This code updates the web query based on what is in B1:B3

```
Sub UpdateQuery()

    Dim sURL As String

    With Sheet1
        sURL = "URL;http://tatts.com/racing/" & .Range("B1").Value & "/" & .Range("b2").Value & "/" & .Range("b3").Value & "/QR"

        .QueryTables(1).Connection = sURL
        .QueryTables(1).Refresh

    End With

End Sub
```

It just builds a string for the URL that I want, updates the Connection property, and refreshes.